# Как изменить мою программу, чтобы сообщение бота менялось при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, inline

Я пишу Telegram бота для изучения C#. И в процессе с толкнулся с проблемой, что не могу реализовать кнопки Inline. Мне необходимо прописать две кнопки: "Назад" и "Дальше", чтобы при нажатии менялось сообщение бота.

**Примерно как на фотографии:**

[image: Пример необходимой кнопки inline]

А вот сам  [telegram bot](https://web.telegram.org/k/#@sportorient_bot)

**Вот моя попытка создания кнопки:**

```
  InlineKeyboardMarkup myInlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(

                                       new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                                       {
                                            new InlineKeyboardButton[] // First row
                                            {
                                                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData( // First Column
                                                    "Назад", // Button Name
                                                    "CallbackQuery1" // Answer you'll recieve
                                                ),
                                                InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData( //Second column
                                                    "Далее", // Button Name
                                                    "CallbackQuery2" // Answer you'll recieve
                                                )
                                            }
                                       }
                                   );

                    botClient.OnCallbackQuery += async (object sc, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
                    {
                        if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "CallbackQuery1")
                        {
                            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "Вы выбрали Назад");
                        }
                        else if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "CallbackQuery2")
                        {
                            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "Вы выбрали Далее");
                        }
                    };
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Здравствуйте, вас привествует телеграм бот по изучению языка программирования C Sharp. Выбирите необходимый блок для изучения. Нажмите кнопку дальше, чтобы продолжить", replyMarkup: myInlineKeyboard);
```

Comment: Этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли? Вот я вижу что вы создали `myInlineKeyboard`, а где его отправили пользователю - не показано.

Comment: Вот отправил пользователю                     await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Здравствуйте, вас привествует телеграм бот по изучению языка программирования C Sharp. Выбирите необходимый блок для изучения. Нажмите кнопку дальше, чтобы продолжить", replyMarkup: myInlineKeyboard);

Comment: Вставьте этот код в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил код, которого не хватало

Comment: Этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли?

Comment: Он работает, но я не знаю как добавить необходимый функционал, чтобы текст менялся при нажатии на кнопку как на боте, который я указал

Comment: Ну, надо наверное отредактировать отправленное сообщение, верно? Вопрос не имеет отношения к кнопкам, получается. Так и написали бы в вопросе, что кнопки работают, а отредактировать сообщение не можете. Вот по-вашему, как бы я об этом догадался только прочитав вопрос? _"при нажатии менялась лекция"_ совершенно ни о чем не говорит, в телеграме нет такой сущности "лекция".

Comment: То есть вопрос должен был звучать как-то так "Как изменить уже отправленное ботом сообщение". Отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он был ближе к сути.

Comment: Теперь вроде правильно